# Keyboard toggles when next tapped

Tags: swiftui

I have multiple TextFields and I set it up so that when I tap next on the keyboard it moves to the next field, but when I tap next, the keyboard disappears and reappears, hides and shows as you can see in the movie

[image]

here's my code

```
struct CreditEditorScreen: View {
    
    enum FocusedField: Hashable {
        case creditor, amount, purpose
    }
    
    @State private var creditor             : String = ""
    @State private var amount               : String = ""
    @State private var purpose              : String = ""
    @State private var date                 : Date = Date()
    @FocusState private var focusedField    : FocusedField?
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                TextField("creditor", text: $creditor)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .creditor)
                    .submitLabel(.next)
                    .onSubmit { focusedField = .amount }
                TextField("amount", text: $amount).keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .amount)
                    .submitLabel(.next)
                    .onSubmit { focusedField = .purpose }
                TextField("purpose", text: $purpose)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .purpose)
                    .submitLabel(.done)
                DatePicker("date", selection: $date, displayedComponents: [.date])
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button("Save") {
                    
                }
            }.onAppear {
                focusedField = .creditor
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is keyboard moving to the next field without this toggle